# mongo clone doesn't do anything

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to clone a remote mongo db to a local one.  I am attempting to follow these instructions:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/clone/

In the mongo console I type:

clone: "username@example.com:password@mymongohost.com:10035"

and the console comes back with:

username@example.com:password@mymongohost.com:10035

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [db.cloneDatabase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.cloneDatabase/#db.cloneDatabase)("username@example.com:password@mymongohost.com:10035") or alternatively passing the `{clone: "..."}` as argument to [db.runCommand()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/#db.runCommand)?

I think you're just missing how you're supposed to *use* those commands as the documentation isn't making it very clear. If you followed the 'copydb' link you might've spotted the example using 'db.copyDatabase()' instead and started wondering maybe there's a wrapper function for clone as well.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I never understand document writers aversion to examples.  Yours works perfectly.